# create rows from columns in a apache spark dataset

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying from a dataset to create a row from existing columns.
Here is my case:

InputDataset

| accountid | payingaccountid | billedaccountid | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MY1U3AAL | 0011t00000MY1U3XXX | 0011t00000ZZ1U3AAL | 2020-06-10 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |

And I would like to have sometthing like this

| accountid | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MY1U3AAL | 2021-06-10 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000MY1U3XXX | 2021-06-10 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000ZZ1U3AAL | 2021-06-10 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |

In the input dataset the columns billedaccounid and payingaccounid are now also in accountid column.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array column with 3 id columns then use explode function to get desired result.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

val df = List(("0011t00000MY1U3AAL", "0011t00000MY1U3XXX", "0011t00000ZZ1U3AAL", "2020-06-10 00:00:00.000000", "NULL"))
    .toDF("accountid", "payingaccountid", "billedaccountid", "startdate", "enddate")

df.select(
    explode_outer(array("accountid","payingaccountid","billedaccountid")).as("accountid"),
    'startdate,'enddate).show(false)
/*
+------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|accountid         |startdate                 |enddate|
+------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|0011t00000MY1U3AAL|2020-06-10 00:00:00.000000|NULL   |
|0011t00000MY1U3XXX|2020-06-10 00:00:00.000000|NULL   |
|0011t00000ZZ1U3AAL|2020-06-10 00:00:00.000000|NULL   |
+------------------+--------------------------+-------+ */
```